# Prisma doesn't regenerate interfaces

Tags: typescript, database, orm, nestjs, prisma

I have `Nest.js` project and I use `Prisma` as my ORM. The problem is next:

I have simple `User` model:

```
model User {
    id               String @id @default(uuid()) @db.Uuid

    firstName        String? @map("first_name") @db.Citext
    lastName         String? @map("last_name") @db.Citext
    phoneNumber      String? @map("phone_number") @unique
    email            String  @unique
    password         String
    twitter          String?
    linkedIn         String? @map("linked_in")
    personalWebsite  String? @map("personal_website")
    title            String?
    bio              String?
    tac              Boolean
    accountConfirm   Boolean @map("account_confirm") @default(false)

    verificationCode VerificationCodes[]
    confirmHashes    ConfirmationHashes[]
    session          Sessions?

    updatedAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("updated_at") @updatedAt @db.Timestamptz(6)
    createdAt DateTime @default(now()) @map("created_at") @db.Timestamptz(6)

    @@map("users")
}
```

What I just did was changing `@@map("user")` to `@@map("users")`. I did migration and generate interfaces. Basically, the name of the table within database has been changed, but not interfaces in code. For example, in code I cannot use:

```
await this.prisma.users.create({...
```

It says - `TS2551: Property 'users' does not exist on type 'PrismaService'.`. And what it does is tell me to change it to `.user`, but that doesn't make sense since I have change it in `schema.prisma`.

I tried to remove `node_modules`, reinstall packages, did build a couple of times, but nothing worked for me. What is the problem? Is there a cache? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@@map` changes the name of the **database** table, not the table generated by Prisma and its TypeScript interfaces.

https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-schema-reference#map-1

In your scenario, the `User` model will always be referred to via `prisma.user`. If you want to access it via `prisma.users`, you have to change the name of the model in Prisma.